# ¿Cómo comprobar si un usuario ya existe antes de guárdalo en la base de datos con php?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo el registro de una persona la cual tiene un documento que debe ser único, `mysql` me envía un error cuando hago un registro igual, quisiera saber como puedo poner una condición con una consulta previa del documento antes de guardar los datos, osea cuando yo escriba el numero en el `input` este me diga que ya ese numero existe en la base de datos o cuando haga clic en el botón guardar, cualquier opción me sirve.

con este código hago la inserción:

```
public  function insertarEmpleado(){


    $sql="INSERT  INTO empleado 


         VALUES(

        '$this->documento',
        '$this->nombres',
        '$this->apellidos',
        '$this->celular',
        '$this->telefono',
        '$this->direccion',
        '$this->estado_civil',
        '$this->perfil',
        '$this->fecha_ingreso',
        '$this->fecha_nacimiento',
        '$this->foto')";

$insert=$this->db->query($sql);

$sql = "INSERT INTO acceso 


 VALUES (0,


 '$this->documento',

 '$this->documento',

 '$this->perfil',

 '$this->documento',

 'inactivo')";



    $insert=$this->db->query($sql);

        }
```

código del `input` de registro:

```
  <div class="form-group">

            <label for="user">DOCUMENTO</label>
            <input type="text"   maxlength="10" name="documento" id="documento" placeholder="Solo caracteres Numericos"   class="form-control" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 58)" min="1"
              required autocomplete="off"/>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Tendrías que usar `AJAX`, para que al perder el foco del `input` haga una consulta o al oprimir el botón y verifique si ese documento ya existe.

Comment: Si lo quieres controlar desde el cliente lo mas recomendable es Ajax, con el cual se puede crear la consulta asicronica sin tener que enviar el formulario, o puede enviar el formulario validar antes del codigo que tienes si el id esta ya en la db y guardar o regresa el error según el resultado de la validación, este es un pequeño tuto de ajax y php
https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/usando-ajax-un-simple-ejemplo-con-php-y-jquery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya te han dicho la forma más efectiva de hacerlo es con `ajax` por lo tanto en el formulario, puedes hacer que se ejecute en el evento que más prefieras, `onclick`, `onchange`, `onblur`, demás, y ese evento ejecutaría el método que hace la petición en `ajax` más o menos así

`PHP`

```
<?php
    $documento = $_POST["documento"];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE documento = '$documento'";

    $rs=$this->db->query($sql);
    if(rs->num_rows > 0){
      echo "1";
     }else{echo "0"; }
?>
```

`JQuery Ajax`
Recuerda importar la librería de `JQuery`

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function verificarDocumento(){
     var documento = $("#documento").val();
     var data = {
        documento : documento // se tiene una variable json y se agrega lo que le vas a mandar, el nombre y el valor
     };

     $.ajax({
      url:"archivo.php", //colocas la ruta de donde está el archivo php
      type: "post",
      data: data, //Los datos que se van a enviar por el post en este caso documento
      success: function(response){
         if(response.trim() == "1"){
             console.log("ya existe");
          }else{console.log("no existe");}
       }
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sería así más o menos, y ya desde el formulario con un evento decides como ejecutar el método, por ejemplo con `onchange`

`HTML`

```
<div class="form-group">

            <label for="user">DOCUMENTO</label>
            <input type="text"   maxlength="10" name="documento" id="documento" placeholder="Solo caracteres Numericos" onchange="verificarDocumento()"  class="form-control" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 58)" min="1"
              required autocomplete="off"/>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
          </div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!